# Prove that $5$ divides the order $G.$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group such that for every subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $[G ∶ H] ≥ 2,$ $5$ divides $[G ∶ H].$ Suppose there is at least one subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $[G ∶ H] \geq 2.$

I can see it says suppose there is a subgroup but I donʻt know how to show that $5$ divides the order of $G$

Comment: Suppose there is at least one subgroup? Done!

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that doesnʻt help me.

Comment: You do not actually need all that information...If G is a finite group, then [G:H] always divides |G| (there are many ways to see that, Lagrange theorem for example). So 5 divides [G:H] implies that 5 divides |G|.

Comment: @Foivos I was thinking about LaGranges theorem but also thinking that no way its that simple. I guess so then.

Comment: @Foivos How would you show that $5$ divided $\mathcal{Z}(G)$, the center I believe its called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a finite $G$, we have $[G:H]=|G|/|H|$.  In particular it's a factor of $|G|$.

But, divisibility is transitive.  So, $5|[G:H]\implies 5||G|$.

Comment: Thanks Chris when I wrote it out from the help of Foivos, it looked like this. Do you have advice for showing that $5$ divides the center? $\mathcal{Z}(G)$

Comment: Not off the top of my head.

Comment: By the class equation.

Comment: The order of $G$, as well as the indices of the nontrivial stabilizers, are divisible by $5$.  The class equation is $|G|=|Z(G)|+[G:G_{x_i}]$, where the $G_{x_i}$ are the stabilizers of representatives of the conjugacy classes.  Everything is divisible by $5$, hence so is $|Z(G)|$.

Comment: Yes the class equation. That definitely makes sense.