# Why is the class equation written the way it's written (i.e. with the $|Z(G)|$ term)

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups

The [conjugacy class equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class#Conjugacy_class_equation) is a nice relation for finite groups, usually stated something like this (taken from Dummit and Foote):

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $g_1, \cdots, g_r$ be representatives of the distinct conjugacy classes of $G$ not contained in the center $Z(G)$ of $G$. Then
>   $$|G| = |Z(G)| + \sum_{i=1}^r|G:C_G(g_i)|.$$

My question is, why do people bother to separate out the elements in the center? The expression $|G:C_G(g)|$ is still well-defined for $g \in Z(G)$: if $g$ commutes with everything then $C_G(g)$ is the whole group, so it'll still contribute $1$ to the total sum. The extra $Z(G)$ term serves only to make the equation longer and more confusing (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733562/why-is-s-specified-to-be-nonempty-in-axler-s-definition-of-function-spaces-m/1734275#1734275) question for another example of what I'm talking about, and why I'd like to avoid it).

Presumably this is just a historical artifact, but if I were to teach this in a class myself I'd want to know 1) if I'm missing any obvious "advantage" to this formulation (so as to be able to pass this on to my students) and 2) any historical details that led this to be written the way it is (context is always illuminating). Your thoughts on either of these would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: didn't you see any of its applications? there is where the advantages arise

Comment: Okay, I buy it: it's just computationally simpler (at least when working "by hand") to find the center of a group than to take each one-element conjugacy class, find its centralizer, find its index... this is probably a good remark to make, thanks for your input!

Comment: For example: "if $|G|=p^n$ for some prime $p$ then $|Z|>1$" and "if $|G|=p^2$ for some prime $p$ then $G$ is abelian" are two classical instances

Comment: A frequent use for separating out the center is to get some divisibility information about these numbers. For example, if the order of $G$ is a power of a prime $p$, then all the terms in the sum are divisible by $p$, but the corresponding terms for central $g_i$ would be $1$. By collecting all those $1$'s into $|Z(G)|$, we get another term that's divisible by $p$ iff the center is nontrivial. Comparing the two sides of the class equation, we get that $p$-groups have nontrivial centers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class equation is a special case of an appliation of the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem for an arbitrary action. If the finite group $G$ acts on the finite set $X$, and we let $\mathcal{O}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{O}_k$ be the orbits of the action, then of course
$$|X| = \sum_{i=1}^k |\mathcal{O}_i|$$
and by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, of $x_i$ is an element of $\mathcal{O}_i$, then $|\mathcal{O}_i| = [G:\mathrm{Stab}_G(x_i)]$, the index of the stabilizer of $x_i$.

But when you are working with general actions, singleton orbits are “silly”; you just have the trivial action $g\cdot x= x$ for all $g\in G$. For the action of $G$ on $X$, what really matters, what *really* gives you information about $G$, are the orbits with more than one element. So it makes sense to divide $X$ into two: $X_0$, consisting of all elements that are fixed pointwise by *every* element of $G$, and $X_1$, the complement of $X_0$ in $X$. If we re-order the orbits so that $X_1=\mathcal{O}_1\cup\cdots\cup\mathcal{O}_m$, and $\mathcal{O}_{m+1},\ldots,\mathcal{O}_k$ are the singleton orbits, then
$$|X| = |X_0|+|X_1| = |X_0| + \sum_{i=1}^m[G:\mathrm{Stab}_G(x_i)],$$
and we separate the $X_0$ because that’s the part of $X$ where the action is trivial.

If we take this general framework to the case where $X=G$ and the action is conjugation, $X_0$ corresponds to $Z(G)$. So separating out the $Z(G)$ makes this fit into the more general framework in which we separate out the part of the set where the action is trivial.

Of course, it just so happens to be useful for the class equation. For example, it makes it obvious that the center of a finite $p$-group is nontrivial, since both $G$ and the sum are congruent to $0$ modulo $p$.

Comment: You mean finite *set* X, not group?

Comment: @Jaspreet yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All the elements of the center have centralizer equal to the whole group, so index $1$.  Thus the order of the center appears.  All the other elements of the group have centralizers with index greater than $1$.

Here is an example of how it can be useful (read the comments):  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3629245/403337

Comment: I'm aware why they're equivalent. I'm just saying that it seems nicer to express it as $|G| = \sum |G:C_G(g_i)|$, with no qualifications on the $g_i$ being in the center (get rid of that ugly and confusing extra term!).

Comment: @fish if you might write $Z$ for the center, it would be less ugly XD

Comment: The center is important enough to separate it out.

Comment: @fish, as Chris is pointing out, the center is an important structure from group theoretic standpoint. So, if we can enucleate its order in some equation, why not to take the chance to make some deal out of it?

Comment: @fish, let's say differently: can you get anything useful from $|G|=\sum[G:C_G(g_i)]$ *as such*?